# old dlls in GAC are still being used

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, assemblies, gac

I have a set up where the assembly is published to the GAC after each build. But My application uses the old dll all the time. After build the new dlls are created in a new folder. The folder names are 7.1.7573.0_*d516cb311 and 7.1.5000.8888*_d516cb311. The second folder being the latest. It seems(from the folder name) my current code is publishing old dll. Is it the reason my application is using old dll? If yes What will I have to do so that currect assembly is published?

Edit:

In the web.config file the assembly is registered under runtime element. And its version is the Version is 7.0.0.0.

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
<qualifyAssembly partialName="dllpartialname" fullName="dllfullname,version=7.0.0.0,publicKeyToken=d516cb311,culture=neutral"/>
</runtime>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Edit2:
Now I know What the problem is. My web project is referencing an assembly which has a version 7.1.7573.0. But the assemblyversion in the assemblyinfo.cs file (of my classlibrary) is 7.1.5000.8888. When I am building the class library project, It is publishing an assembly having a version 7.1.5000.8888(i.e. the assemblyversion in assemblyinfo.cs file) to the GAC. But as my web project is having a reference to 7.1.7573.0. , It still uses the dll in the folder 7.1.7573.0_d516cb311 and ignores the other folder.

Edit 3:
Facing a different problem now. I updated the assemlyversion in the assemblyinfo.cs file. But when I try to build it it changes are reverted automatically. It says this file has been modified outside the source editor. Why is this happening ? Does anyone have an idea about it?

Thanks,
Syd

Comment: could you put in how your config is referencing the files? something like `<add assembly="ninject, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c7192dc5380945e7, processorArchitecture=MSIL"/>`

Comment: It is working the way it should, giving you the assembly you asked for.  Some tender loving care to the version number would be wise, having build number 7573 be *older* than build number 5000 is not pretty.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is, the GAC always wins.

When you reference a dll, even if you reference a different local dll, the version in GAC will win.

Either remove the older dll from your GAC

or

Add a new reference to your new local version of the dll and change the config line to match the version number of your new dll.

The version number can be found in the properties of the file.

Comment: Removing the older DLL will merely bomb his program.  Version number always wins.